# How to display currency values in UILabel?

Tags: swift3, uilabel

Designed Label

[image: designed label]

I want to design the label as shown in the image in a single label.

Can anyone help me?
­

Comment: Check out `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Either use a `NumberFormatter` or an `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: I tried NSAttributedString but the number sets side by side but not as shown in the image

Comment: That's pretty easy. Format the "99" to be in a smaller font size and with a higher baseline. What's the hard part for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3.0

```
let fnt = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 50)
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$499", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: fnt?.withSize(50) as Any])
    attributedString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: fnt?.withSize(20) as Any, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 20], range: NSRange(location: 2, length: 2))
    label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an attributed string and give the "99" a smaller font size and higher baseline. Here's an example in Swift 4 (sorry, I don't have time to translate this backwards into Swift 3 or earlier):

```
let s = "$499"
let mas = NSMutableAttributedString(string: s, attributes: [
    .foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
    .font : UIFont(name:"Helvetica", size:50)!
])
let r2 = s.index(before: s.endIndex)
let r1 = s.index(before: r2)
let r = NSRange(r1...r2, in:s)
mas.addAttributes([
    .font : UIFont(name:"Helvetica", size:20)!,
    .baselineOffset : 20
    ], range: r)
```

Now assign that to the label's `attributedText`. Playing around with the other details is up you.

[image]